# chrome - hidden div around iframe with PHP inside

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

this ones really stumped me
basically, i have a hidden div (hidden tab content) around an iframe which is meant to load a PHP file manager (KCfinder):

```
<div id="contentfilemanager" style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="filemanager" src="scripts/kcfinder/browse.php"></iframe>
</div>
```

but when i go to load the page in Chrome, it keeps loading for ever, and the page is effectively frozen. it displays the entire page, but nothing is clickable.

this does not happen in any other browser i have tried (firefox, ie9). and even weirder, when i go to load a non PHP page, it loads fine.

is it possible that this a problem with the page within the iframe?

Comment: I actually get this with Chrome on a variety of pages, not just `<iframe>`s. I have to kill the tab and repeatedly try loading it. If you can whip up a static-content example, you can file a bug report!

Comment: If you can produce a test case, please do file a bug at http://new.crbug.com/ Chrome shouldn't lock up on you, period.